# creating a File with a JSON file from my resources folder

Tags: java, json, file, nullpointerexception

[image: Picture]

^Picture of my source folder.

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File questionsFile = new 
File(classLoader.getResource("/Questions.json").getFile());
```

Line 4 is throwing a null pointer exception and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in `/Questions.json`, `/` means the root of your arborescence. You want a relative path, try

```
File questionsFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("Questions.json").getFile());
```

Comment: I tried this. It still comes up with a null pointer exception.